# How to count different aswers in R

Tags: r, categorical-data

I am analyzing a questionnaire and I've written the code below to count how many answers there are to each question. The questions are in columns and the answer is coded as a number, where 1=a, 2=b.
The main objective is to count how many times an answer was chosen, ignoring pattern to summarize the information.

DS is the data frame, containing questions Q_092 to Q_096. I have the code to change column names, but it expects a fixed number of columns.

Is there a prettier way to do it?

```
conta_respostas <- function (arr_resp) {
  arr_resp[(is.na(arr_resp))]<-99
  arr_result =  c(
    sum(arr_resp[(arr_resp=="1")])/1,
    sum(arr_resp[(arr_resp=="2")])/2,
    sum(arr_resp[(arr_resp=="3")])/3,
    sum(arr_resp[(arr_resp=="4")])/4,
    sum(arr_resp[(arr_resp=="5")])/5,
    sum(arr_resp[(arr_resp=="6")])/6,
    sum(arr_resp[(arr_resp=="7")])/7,
    sum(arr_resp[(arr_resp=="8")])/8,
    sum(arr_resp[(arr_resp=="9")])/9,
    sum(arr_resp[(arr_resp=="10")])/10,
    sum(arr_resp[(arr_resp=="99")])/99
  )
}
adply(DS, 2, conta_respostas)
     X1  V1   V2   V3   V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11
1 Q_092 431 1987 5053 1388  0  0  0  0  0   0  36
2 Q_093 281 1489 5728 1336  0  0  0  0  0   0  61
3 Q_094 594 3380 4365  519  0  0  0  0  0   0  37
4 Q_095  89  216 5042 3511  0  0  0  0  0   0  37
5 Q_096 213 1764 5384 1511  0  0  0  0  0   0  23
```

Answer (score 1):

what it sounds like your data looks like:

```
DS <- data.frame(
  'Q_092' = c(1, 3, 4, 5, 2, 99, 10),
  'Q_093' = c(2, 5, 6, 2, 99, 1, 1),
  'Q_094' = c(3, 5, 6, 2, 4, 7, 8),
  'Q_095' = c(10, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 6),
  'Q_096' = c(1, 3, 4, 5, 2, 99, 10)
  )
DS

  Q_092 Q_093 Q_094 Q_095 Q_096
1     1     2     3    10     1
2     3     5     5     5     3
3     4     6     6     5     4
4     5     2     2     6     5
5     2    99     4     7     2
6    99     1     7     8    99
7    10     1     8     6    10
```

Recreating your code:

```
library(plyr)

conta_respostas <- function (arr_resp) {
  arr_resp[(is.na(arr_resp))]<-99
  arr_result =  c(
    sum(arr_resp[(arr_resp=="1")])/1,
    sum(arr_resp[(arr_resp=="2")])/2,
    sum(arr_resp[(arr_resp=="3")])/3,
    sum(arr_resp[(arr_resp=="4")])/4,
    sum(arr_resp[(arr_resp=="5")])/5,
    sum(arr_resp[(arr_resp=="6")])/6,
    sum(arr_resp[(arr_resp=="7")])/7,
    sum(arr_resp[(arr_resp=="8")])/8,
    sum(arr_resp[(arr_resp=="9")])/9,
    sum(arr_resp[(arr_resp=="10")])/10,
    sum(arr_resp[(arr_resp=="99")])/99
  )
}
adply(DS, 2, conta_respostas)

      X1 V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11
 1 Q_092  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0   1   1
 2 Q_093  2  2  0  0  1  1  0  0  0   0   1
 3 Q_094  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0   0   0
 4 Q_095  0  0  0  0  2  2  1  1  0   1   0
 5 Q_096  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0   1   1
```

Without having to write that function, you can do something like this:

```
t(apply(DS, 2, function(x) table(factor(x, levels = c('1', '2', '3', '4', '5',
                                                      '6', '7', '8', '9', '10',
                                                      '99')))))
```

This will do the following:

- transform your data into factors with the levels as input in `levels =`.  Having your data as a factor will allow you to avoid the levels where no respondents chose that response to be left out.
- This creates a table for each variable with a cell for each of the factor levels.
- This function is applied over the five variable columns that you are interested in.
- Finally, the output from the apply() function is transposed to match the output from your original output:

  ```
         1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 99   
   Q_092 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0  1  1
   Q_093 2 2 0 0 1 1 0 0 0  0  1  
   Q_094 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0  0  0  
   Q_095 0 0 0 0 2 2 1 1 0  1  0  
   Q_096 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0  1  1
  ```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use the apply() function with FUN=table.  The only issue here is that your tables may be of different lengths, thus the final result may not be combined row-by-row.